# Can you use Numpy Slice to Change values without known Index?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have a 2D array with hundreds slices. An example of one of those slices below:

```
example_slice = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

I am interested in changing the 2's in the slice but do not know that they will always be 2's or that they will always be in the same index location.

I do know that the first and last 2 will always be separated from the 0's by some value - a 1 in this example.

Is there a way to write a np.slice that will be able to change the 2's into 3's by adding 1, if I do not know the index location?

my code attempt with the help of others is below:

```
example_array = np.array(2D_Surface)
sub_array = example_array[:, 1:-1]
sub_array[sub_array > 1] += 1
```

but this attempt adds 1 to every value in the list turning the slice into:

```
incorrect_slice = [0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0]
```

instead of the desired slice

```
correct_slice = [0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: there's no `np.slice`.  Array indexing, with or without `slice` is by position, not value.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Comment from @hpaulj:

> `where` is optional here.

> The key step is example_slice == 2 which tests all array elements to 2. The result is an array of true/false. where converts that to index array(s)

So, you can simply use:

```
example_slice[example_slice == 2] = 3

# OR

example_slice[example_slice == 2] += 1
```

---

Are you looking for [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
example_slice = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0])
example_slice[np.where(example_slice == 2)] = 3
```

Output:

```
>>> example_slice
array([0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: The key step is `example_slice == 2` which tests all array elements to `2`. The result is an array of true/false.  `where` converts that to index array(s).  I think `where` is optional here.  `example_slice[example_slice == 2] = 3`

Comment: @hpaulj You are totally right. It was late, I didn't think too much :p

Comment: That makes sense! would you have any recommendations on automating the process such that even if I didn't know the number would be a 2 I could still add 1 to whatever value is in those locations?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Some supplement to the **Corralien**. There is a simplified/different version of

> np.where()

```
example_slice = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0])
np.where(example_slice==2,example_slice+1,example_slice) 
# np.where(condition, if True yield example_slice+1, if False yield example_slice)
```

Output is

```
array([0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0])
```